# ASP.NET MVC Blog plugins?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, blogs, orchardcms-1.6, blogengine.net

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project.

I don't want to implement Blog functionality (tags, posts, comments, categorization, etc.) but would really like to find something to plug into that has all of this out of the box.

You know, something like mysite.com/blog that I can theme up to look how I want it to, possibly some customizations, but mostly just a blog roll.

Does anyone have any recommendations here?

Does BlogEngine.NET or OrchardCMS do these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlogEngine.net does have all the features you mentioned.  If you are comfortable with having the url be /blog then you can create an application in your IIS install and use it directly out of the box.  You can also customize the look and feel of everything customer facing with themes.  The themes are site.master pages and a couple of user controls which you can style with css.

**Resources**

- [BlogEngine.net Homepage](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/)
- [Themes](https://francis.bio/blogengine-themes/)